# Cannot read fields with parameterized MongoDB query in Jasper Reports

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports

I have the following collection in MongoDB

[Collection](https://codeshare.io/oYev0)

I want to create a list for each `account` for which I created a dataset with the following query

```
{ runCommand : { aggregate : 'case', 
                pipeline : [ { $project : { accounts : 1 }},
                             { $unwind  : '$accounts'},

                                     ]
           }
}
```

Now inside the list I want to represent the `transactions` array in a table. I am not able to figure out what dataset query should I use for it. Currently I am using this

```
{ runCommand : { aggregate : 'case', 
                pipeline : [ { $project : { accounts : 1 }},
                             { $unwind  : '$accounts'},
                             { $unwind : '$accounts.transactions'},
                             { $match:{'accounts.accountNumber':'$P!{accNumber}'}}
                                     ]
           }
}
```

Here I have used a paramter called `accNumber` to which I pass the current Account number for which to display the transactions. However, when I give this query in the dataset, it is not able to read any fields. But if I hard code an actual account number, it is able to read all the fields. In my case, without any fields, I am not able to make my table. Any suggestions?

Comment: How is this question related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361748/represent-a-list-of-tables-in-jasper-reports

Comment: This is one of the things I tried to solve my earlier question. But I am stuck here again.

Comment: Might be connected to using `'$P!{accNumber}'` instead of `$P{accNumber}`. Are there specific reasons you want this to be a text?

Comment: The `accountNumber` might be alphanumeric instead of just integer

Comment: Then the field type should be String. I am not sure if P!{} would print the string correctly for the query. Especially since you wrote hard coding the acc number works.